# How do i create a decorator for a function with added functionality?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to refactor my code. What I am currently doing is extracting data from an ad platform API endpoint and transforming and uploading it to big query. I have the following code which works but I want to refactor it after having learnt about decorators.

**Decorators are very powerful and useful tool in Python since it allows programmers to modify the behavior of function or class. Decorators allow us to wrap another function in order to extend the behavior of wrapped function, without permanently modifying it.**

```
import datauploader
import ndjson
import os

def upload_ads_details(extractor, access_token, acccount_id, req_output, 
                       bq_client_name, bq_dataset_id, bq_gs_bucket, 
                       ndjson_local_file_path, ndjson_file_name):


    # Function to Extract data from the API/Ad Platform
    ads_dictionary = extractor.get_ad_dictionary(access_token, acccount_id)

    # Converting data to ndjson for upload to big query
    output_ndjson = ndjson.dumps(ads_dictionary)
    with open(ndjson_local_file_path, 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(output_ndjson)
    print(os.path.abspath(ndjson_local_file_path))

    # This code below remains the same for all the other function calls
    if req_output:
        # Inputs for the uploading functions
        print("Processing Upload")
        partition_by = "_insert_time"
        str_gcs_file_name = ndjson_file_name
        str_local_file_name = ndjson_local_file_path
        gs_bucket = bq_gs_bucket
        gs_file_format = "JSON"
        table_id = 'ads_performance_stats_table'
        table_schema = ads_dictionary_schema

        # Uploading Function
        datauploader.loadToBigQuery(
            bq_client_name,
            bq_dataset_id,
            table_id,
            table_schema,
            partition_by,
            str_gcs_file_name,
            str_local_file_name,
            gs_bucket,
            gs_file_format,
            autodetect=False,
            req_partition=True,
            skip_leading_n_row=0
        )
```

Comment: Just refactoring for it's own sake is often just asking for trouble... Do you have a specific use-case in mind of what you want to do with a decorator? E.g. what functionality do you want to extract out of this function?

Comment: Just because a tool exists doesn't mean you have to use it everywhere for everything...  And I fail to see what you'd want to extract into a decorator in your example snippet actually.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am looking for abstracting the repetitive part. Especially the uploading function. I am currently reviewing the way which could help me do that.